# Deep copy is causing Maximum call stack size exceeded - there is no loop

Tags: javascript, clone

This is my deep copy function:

```
    const deepCopy = (inObject) => {

     let outObject, value, key

     if (typeof inObject !== "object" || inObject === null) {
      return inObject
     }

     outObject = Array.isArray(inObject) ? [] : {}

     for (key in inObject) {
      value = inObject[key]

      outObject[key] = deepCopy(value)
    }

    return outObject
  }
```

When I run:

```
  let numTicketsSought = nonLastMinuteTickets.map(e=> { 

  e.relevantTicket = deepCopy(userEvent.tickets.find(f => f.ticketTypeID === e.ticketTypeID))

    })
```

I get the error `Maximum call stack size exceeded`

I don't understand why. There isn't an infinite loop.

Where am I going wrong?

Below are the data structures to give clarity -

nonLastMinuteTickets is an array with an object:

```
[{}]
```

userEvent is an object with an array of objects. This is what I need to deep clone:

```
userEvent {
  _id: 5eb99e904b502108419251fd,
  tickets: [ {}, {}, {}],
}
```

Comment: `deepCopy` recursively calls itself, so yes, it's possible with the "right" data structure to encounter that error. it's hard to say what specifically is happening without an example of the object you're intending to clone though.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've included further detail on the data structure

Comment: I assume you've moved on; nonetheless, this post remains. One way to narrow down the possibilities is to break your function apart, and test it in pieces, and with alternatives. I'd first try to run deepCopy(userEvent.tickets.find(f => f.ticketTypeID === e.ticketTypeID)) by itself... if no problems, then look at how you are using map... if problems, try running JSON.stringify(userEvent.tickets.find(f => f.ticketTypeID === e.ticketTypeID) to see if perhaps the problem is a circular reference within (userEvent.tickets.find(f => f.ticketTypeID === e.ticketTypeID).